# Django REST framework cross model endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have these 3 models

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)

class Eater(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)

class Transaction(models.Model):
   eater = models.ForeignKey('Eater', related_name='transactions')
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant', related_name='transactions')
```

How can I write an endpoint like `eater/1/restaurant` to query for all the restaurant that `eater1` has a transaction with?

My DB is in PostgreSQL if that matters.

Comment: If you want to run queries based on URLs, you may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can just do

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'], url_path='restaurants')
def eater_resturants(request, eater_id):
    res = Restaurant.objects.filter(transactions__eater_id=eater_id)
    serializer = RestaurantSerializer(deals, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Given this is a method in model.ViewSet

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Transaction model for the same

```
Transaction.objects.filter(eater=eater1).values('restaurant')
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do this in regular Django. I guess I am asking what's the standard to do this in REST framework.